# Opening another activity based on number of filled editTexts

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The `app` has a `MainActivity` with 6 `editText` fields, and a `button`. There are 5 more activities, named `Activity2`, `Activity3`, etc. Now, When a user enters names in `editText` fields, and press a `button`, the `app` should find out how many `editText` fields are filled, and open the activity with a corresponding number in it's name.

Example:

- If only one field is filled, a `toast` should appear, saying **More players**.
- If two fields are filled, `app` opens `Activity2`.
- If three fields are filled, `app` opens `Activity3`, etc.

Now, to the problem. I am missing something out, and can't find out what. Here is MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText editText1,editText2,editText3,editText4,editText5,editText6;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
    editText1 = findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText2 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editText3 = findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    editText4 = findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    editText5 = findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    editText6 = findViewById(R.id.editText6);


    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int filledFileds = countFilledFields();
            Log.d("filled", String.valueOf(filledFileds));
            Class newClass = MainActivity.class;

            switch (filledFileds){

                case 1:

                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text = "You need more players!";
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                    toast.show();

                    break;

                case 2:

                    newClass = Activity2.class;
                    System.out.println("Activity2");

                    break;

                case 3:

                    newClass = Activity3.class;
                    System.out.println("Activity3");

                    break;

                case 4:

                    newClass = Activity4.class;
                    System.out.println("Activity4");

                    break;

                case 5:

                    newClass = Activity5.class;
                    System.out.println("Activity5");

                    break;

                case 6:

                    newClass = Activity6.class;
                    System.out.println("Activity6");

                    break;

                default:


            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, newClass);
        }
    });
}

private int countFilledFields() {

    ArrayList<EditText> editTexts = new ArrayList<>();
    editTexts.add(editText1);
    editTexts.add(editText2);
    editTexts.add(editText3);
    editTexts.add(editText4);
    editTexts.add(editText5);
    editTexts.add(editText6);

    int filledNumber = 0;

    for(int i = 0;i < editTexts.size() ;i++){

        if(editTexts.get(i).getText()!=null && !editTexts.get(i).getText().toString().matches("")){
            filledNumber += 1;
        }

    }
    return filledNumber;
}
```

}

The log shows the exact number, something is not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your click listener, with the `switch` omitted for brevity:

> ```
> btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>     @Override
>     public void onClick(View v) {
>
>         int filledFileds = countFilledFields();
>         Log.d("filled", String.valueOf(filledFileds));
>         Class newClass = MainActivity.class;
>
>         switch (filledFileds){
>             ...
>         }
>
>         Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, newClass);
>     }
> ```

The problem is at the very end: you've created an `Intent` object ... but you're not doing anything with it. Probably you have just forgotten a `startActivity()` call:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, newClass);
startActivity(intent);
```

Also, looking this over, you have a problem with the case where the user only enters one EditText. As written, you'll still try to start a new activity (you'll just start a new copy of the same MainActivity, which is probably a bad idea). A better idea would be to only start the new activity if the user fills out enough EditTexts:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int filledFileds = countFilledFields();
        Log.d("filled", String.valueOf(filledFileds));
        Class newClass = null;

        switch (filledFileds){
            ...
        }

        if (newClass != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, newClass);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for noticing. I guess that would make problems further on. Good eye you got there :)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing one thing:

```
 startActivity(intent);
```